# Swift StoryBoard Errors

Tags: swift, storyboard

I just switched from Objective-C to Swift and started on a simple app.
I have made a custom storyboard and code that should load it, but it does not load it and gives me 11DB error and Thread 1 SIGBART error. However, if I use the launcher storyboard as what to load from, my view loads, but in some views the constraints do not work properly.
Thanks.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhwrt.png)

I want the view to be my MainGameStoryboard, but it doesn't load it if I declare it under the main settings. However, if I declare launcher storyboard the view loads, but the constraints are not existent.

Comment: Does it show anything in the console log?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a storyboard, you shouldn't have to load the nib file yourself.  If you look in the settings for your project it has a place where you give the application the name of the main storyboard and it will be loaded for you.

Click on the project icon at the top of the file list and you should see project settings.  Across the top choose the "General" category and look for the "Deployment Info" settings.  There is a popup titled "Main Interface" that should let you select the storyboard to load when your application starts up.

In the particular case of your code, you ask the system to create your main view controller from a nib file, and get back an Optional.  That optional might be nil, but you never check it to see before trying to set it to the Window's main view controller.  You should always check the value of optionals before using them.  That might be what is causing your crash.

Comment: I did do that and that is what causes the error. If I use the other storyboard, then it does load my view, but the constraints don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You load UIStoryboard view controllers with [UIStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](http://uistoryboard%20instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier), not with UINib.